# Android popup - passing arguments to event handlers

Tags: android, popup

I have a NavigationView with menu.
When any menuitem is long pressed, I inflate a popup which gives the user various options/buttons. Each button has an event handler.

I need those handlers to know which menuitem originally triggered the popup.

What I am missing is the knowledge of how to pass that identity along the flow of objects.

In the posted code,  the menuitem is longclicked, I pass menutem as a view to the popup constructor. 
Yet no idea how to then pass it to the popup Button's event handler.

I am considering as an alternative, simply setting a variable with the id when the longpress occurs, and then reading that variable back again in the final handler.... but that does feel like a cheat and would require managing to ensure synchronising with events.

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        pop(v);
        return true;
    }


public void pop(View v){

LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
  (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  

final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
    popupView, 
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

    Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id of menuitem here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 50, -30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you just want to pass the id of menuitem tapped on to pop method and later display that value in Toast.
In that case considering you can cast the id value into string, you can use `setTag()` and `getTag()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
{
    v.setTag(place the id of menuitem tapped here);
        pop(v);
        return true;
}


public void pop(View v)
{

LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
  (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  

final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
    popupView, 
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

    Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(v.getTag()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 50, -30);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, though I tried just for completeness. The view passing into onlongpress is indeed the menu item. However the view passing into the button event is the button itself.